# How to increase listview performance?

Tags: android, database, listview, android-asynctask

I have a scenario where i have to do following task:
1. populate a list-view.
2. perform database operation which is very time consuming task.
3. database processing/operation time is sometime unpredictable.

I have used listView using holder pattern, now it is working faster than earlier but still taking significant time. What else i can do to improve the performance. 
I have an idea but i am afraid whether it will be good to implement or not. Idea is to put the database operation in AsyncTask and update my listview there only.
But i am afraid of doing so is because my listview is totally dependent on database result. So i can display something on Listview only when i am done with DB operation

Please suggest is using Async task will be good approach and please suggest any other idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Holder approach is good. Use that in your adapters always. Make sure you are reusing the convert views as well.

Using an `AsyncTask` is the best option. But you don't have to wait for the entire operation to complete. Read up on how `AsyncTask` works. Use the `publishProgress()` method in your `doInBackground()` of the `AsyncTask` to give batches of data to your list.

For example, if you have to process 100 rows, process 10, then do a `publishProgress()` which will update the list with those 10 rows. When you process the next batch, update the list with `publishProgress()` again.

Comment: sounds good. i will try and if any issue is faced, i will come back here.